# Affects of object assignment within a function on global object values

Tags: javascript, object, pass-by-reference

Can someone please help explain why the value property of obj1 remains the same while in obj2 it changes? I know it has to do with obj1 being assigned to obj2 within the change function but I'm not exactly sure why. Thanks!

```js
let obj1 = {
  value: "a"
}

let obj2 = {
  value: "b"
}


function change(obj1, obj2) {
  obj1 = obj2
  obj1.value = "c"
}

change(obj1, obj2);


console.log("obj1: ", obj1, "obj2: ",obj2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's rename some variables so you can see what's going on

```
let obj1 = {
  value: "a"
}

let obj2 = {
  value: "b"
}


function change(param1, param2) {
  param1 = param2
  param1.value = "c"
}

change(obj1, obj2);


console.log("obj1: ", obj1, "obj2: ",obj2);
```

Now as you can see, `obj1` is never changed. What you are changing is parameter of `change` function that is named the same as variable from outer scope.

Comment: What I'm wondering is why does the param1.value = "c" line within the change function update the value of obj2 but not obj1?

Comment: Because you never assigned `obj2` to `obj1` and you change `obj2`

Answer (score 1):

This is because variables of objects are actually pointers to the object. That's why when they are passed to a function, any changes of the pointer properties would change the actual object. Whereas, if you simply assign a value to a variable of type object, then the pointer itself is changed, not the object.

So `obj1 = obj2` sets the obj1 pointer to be obj2 pointer. Now, if `obj1.value = "c"` then a property of the object obj1 (which is now obj2) will change, affecting the original object.

Comment: I understand. Say we rename the parameters in the change function to pointer1 and pointer2 (as these parameters are the pointers to the address in memory with our object values). When we assign pointer1 = pointer2 in the change function, we are now saying the pointer1 variable within the change function is now a pointer to the same address as pointer2. Assigning pointer1 = pointer2 does not affect the address that obj1 is pointing to, so obj1 value remains the same. Meanwhile the address in memory that obj2 is pointing to has been updated with value = "c" and therefore it is updated.